# HQL where clause with variable inserted

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, toad

I need to insert a variable into an existing HQL where clause as follows:

```
java.sql.Timestamp currentDate = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

Query q = em.createQuery("from fAdjustmentReason a where a.startDate >= " + currentDate + " and a.endDate <= " + currentDate);
```

I get the following error message when I do the above:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 18 near line 1, column 79 
        [from gov.va.med.domain.fee.AdjustmentReason a where a.startDate >= 1969-12-31 18:00:00.0 and a.endDate <= 1969-12-31 18:00:00.0]
```

Should I just add a `currentDate` field to the existing `AdjustmentReason` model class even though it's not in the DB to make this more straightforward?

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Hint: for dates you can use `BETWEEN` clause, eg. `SELECT a FROM entity WHERE startDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate`

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating `Query` object, you should use `setParameter` to set the dates in your query eg.

```
 Query q = em.createQuery("from fAdjustmentReason a where a.startDate >= :0 and a.endDate <= :1");
q.setParameter(0,dateFrom);
q.setParameter(1,dateFrom);
```

That is the reason of prepared statement.
Complete example can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

This way your are doing its not the best way, it makes you code vulnerable to SQL injection, the correct way of doing it and solving your problem is the following:

```
 Query q = em.createQuery("from fAdjustmentReason a where a.startDate >= :startDate and a.endDate <= :endDate")
.setParameter("starDate", currentDate)
.setParameter("endDate", currentDate)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your welcome! Please, accept the answer so other people with the same problem can see it more easly.